# Failure to compile Linq Method in App_Code

Tags: asp.net, linq, iis

I've been scratching my head for what seems like ages. I'm sure its really simple to fix but I can't see it.

I have a class in App_Code that uses a bit of Linq.

```
var siteMap = SiteMapWrapper.BuildSiteMap(true);
var currentTopLevelParent = siteMap.Single(s => s.IsActive);
if (currentTopLevelParent != null)
```

I've developed this locally and all works fine. When I transfer to IIS hosting the same class fails to compile. I receive:

```
does not contain a definition for 'Single' and no extension method 'Single' 
accepting a  first argument of type 'SiteMapWrapper' could be found (are you 
missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I confirmed that the virtual dir is running .NET 2.0 as it should. I also confirmed that the correct assemblies are being loaded in the web.config.

```
<compilation debug="true">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
    <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

I've tried adding namespaces directives in web.config also but no luck. Can anyone think of anything else to try?

Many thanks.

Comment: Just my own custom class for wrapping sitemap. Nothing complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will find that the server does not have 3.5 installed.

Answer (score 0):

Add `using System.Linq;` to the top of the `.cs` file.

Also, make sure that `SiteMapWrapper` implements `IEnumerable<T>`.

**EDIT**: I didn't notice that it works on the local machine.
Make sure that the server has the correct versions of all of the dependent assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

LINQ actually requires .NET 3.0 (3.5 is better), not 2.0.  Make sure the AppPool is configured appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Change the **Build Action** Property of your .cs file from **Content** to **Compile**.

[See this article](http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com.eg/2009/07/appcode-folder-doesnt-work-with-web.html) for more info.